# Uploading a small photo to orient db using rest API

Tags: android, json, orientdb

I have the following table on orient database

```
create class person extends V
create property person.image Binary
create property person.name string
```

I am using http/REST to to upload a image into orient db

http://:2480/document/ is the url

I had tried the following ways

1) encoded the image to base64 using the library available in android 4 and created a json which contains this base64 data and tried to post it to the rest server,
I get the following error message

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OSerializationException:
>   Error on unmarshalling JSON content for record #-1:-1
>
> --> com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 63 in array position 0

I tried to use the apache Code to encode the same image to base64, still similar error message.

I also tried the following 
byte [] base64=Base64.encode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
String str=new String(base64)
and used this str in the json creation and sent the json, but no success.

I also tried to place the binary in the _ + str + _ as mentioned in the following link
https://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Types
but with no success.

Can anyone help me posting the image data.

I am able to post and put other data types using OrientDB rest server.

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: 2014-01-17 09:30:13:642 INFO Indexes restore after crash was finished. [OIndexManagerShared]com.orientechnologies.common.io.OIOException: Bad Base64 input character decimal 92 in array position 90
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.OBase64Utils.decode(OBase64Utils.java:1160)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.OBase64Utils.decode(OBase64Utils.java:1213)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.OBase64Utils.decode(OBase64Utils.java:1180)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer

Answer (score -1):

For uploading images (BLOB) to OrientDB, there seems to be some upload command supported on REST by OrientDB. It has not been documented yet, so nothing can be done except trying luck. Hopefully OrientDB guys will document the command and its usage soon.

Check - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/ahrCcp33udA

==========

**[UPDATE]**

The HTTP REST command is uploadSingleFile and can be used as below:

*http://{host server}:2480/uploadSingleFile/{database}*

This is a POST call and file is sent as payload. Try to explore how OrientDB Studio is trying to upload an image to server. OrientDB Studio is also a web app developed in BootStrap + AngularJS + OrientDB, so a good start point to understand. In OrientDB Studio there is an option to upload an image when you edit record. Unfortunately at my end, even Studio image upload functionality is also giving the same exception error that you are seeing in your case.